# c++ find_if lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

What is wrong with the code below?  It is supposed to find an element in the list of structs if the first of the struct's members equals to 0. The compiler complains about the lambda argument not being of type predicate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

struct S
{
    int S1;
    int S2;
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<S> l;
    S s1;
    s1.S1 = 0;
    s1.S2 = 0;
    S s2;
    s2.S1 = 1;
    s2.S2 = 1;
    l.push_back(s2);
    l.push_back(s1);

    list<S>::iterator it = find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), [] (S s) { return s.S1 == 0; } );
}
```

Comment: I just compiled your code with g++ 4.6.3 and everything compiles properly. No error message here. Which compiler are you using? Maybe it doesn't understand lambdas yet.

Comment: I also compiled this code (with VC10) and got zero errors or warnings, it works as expected when run.

What compiler are you using?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Aha.  Now I feel stupid.  The compiler gave a warning : lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]

I assumed this meant it would be enabled by default.  Turns out it wasn't.  Silly me.  Thanks for helping out nonetheless.

Comment: No, it means the actual warning is enabled by default (and not triggered by some compiler flag like `-Wall`).

Comment: I didn't find this question too localized honestly. I didn't even look at the question in fact. A simple glance at the answer was enough to remember the implementation

Comment: Use of Lambdas in C++ is too localized?  Ridiculous!  This is about how to use the C++ language.  The answer just helped me remember the syntax.

Answer (score 52):

Code works fine on VS2012, just one recommendation, pass object by reference instead of pass by value:

```
list<S>::iterator it = find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), [] (const S& s) { return s.S1 == 0; } );
```

Comment: [&] <--- will capture outer variables by reference, too pass object by reference you have to use (S& s)

Comment: Just wanted to add that this works fine with GCC/G++ 4.7 as well.