# How to use iterator for finding position of object in vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator

I have method which chec is client objects exists (by its name) and returns its position:

```
   int Program::checkClient(string userName){
      vector<Client> *ptr = &(impl->clients);
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < ptr->size(); i++){
         if(ptr->at(i).getName() == userName){
            return i;
         }
      }
      return -1;
   }
```

The problem is that I get warning, because of `i < ptr->size()`. I believe I need to use iterator for this. But how to do it correctly, because not only do I need to run through loop, but also return int as a result, of where it was found. Any ideas? i tried doing something like this, but had no luck:

```
   int Program::checkClient(string userName){
      vector<Client> *ptr = &(impl->clients);
      vector<Client>::iterator it;
      for (it.ptr->begin(); it < it.ptr->end(); it++){
         if(ptr->at(it).getName() == userName){
            return it;
         }
      }
      return -1;
   }
```

I get an error to similar places like this: `it.ptr->begin()`.

Comment: don't, roll your own, use [`std::find_if`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13394222/847349)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use iterators; you haven't mentioned what warning you're getting, but it's probably because you're comparing an `int` to `vector<Client>::size_type`, which is, in all likelihood, an unsigned type. Change the declaration of `i` to

```
std::vector<Client>::size_type i;
```

---

Now, you're getting errors in your iterator code because its syntax is incorrect. The for loop should look like this:

```
for(it = ptr->begin(), it != ptr->end(); ++it) { ... }
```

You can find the index of the item the iterator is currently pointing at using [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

```
return std::distance(ptr->begin(), it);
```

---

Additionally, as mentioned in the comments above, it'd be better to use `std::find_if` for this, especially if you have a compiler that supports lambda expressions.

```
auto it = std::find_if(impl->clients.begin(),
                       impl->clients.end(),
                       [&]( Client const& c ) {
                          return c.getName() == userName;
                       } );
return (it != impl->clients.end()) ? 
         std::distance(impl->clients.begin(), it) : -1;
```

Comment: Huge thanks goes to you sir :) I will accept the answer after a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
int Program::checkClient(string userName)
{
    vector<Client> * ptr = &(impl->clients);
    vector<Client>::iterator it;
    int count=0; //for counting the position
    for (it=ptr->begin(); it!=ptr->end(); ++it)
    {
        ++count;
        if( (*it).getName() == userName )
        {
            return count;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For searching/finding I prefer using `while`, it's easier to understand.
You'd rather use `const&` for your method parameter.

So it'd give something like that:

```
int Program::checkClient(string const& userName) const
{
    vector<Client> const& clients = impl->clients;
    vector<Client>::const_iterator it = clients.begin();
    while (it != clients.end() && it->getName() != userName)
        ++it;
    return it != clients.end() ? it - clients.begin() : -1;
}
```