# std::find_if and lambda referencing structure field

Tags: c++11, lambda, stl

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13394000/1270789) we have:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

struct S
{
    int S1;
    int S2;
};

int main()
{
    std::list<S> l;
    S s1;
    s1.S1 = 0;
    s1.S2 = 0;
    S s2;
    s2.S1 = 1;
    s2.S2 = 1;
    l.push_back(s2);
    l.push_back(s1);

    auto it = std::find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), [] (S s)
        { return s.S1 == 0; } );
}
```

But, if I want to find a match for `s1.S1`, I might try:

```
auto it = std::find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), [s1.S1] (S s)
    { return s.S1 == s1.S1; } );
```

I get a compiler error, however. This works:

```
auto foo = s1.S1;
auto it = std::find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), [foo] (S s)
    { return s.S1 == foo; } );
```

I think I understand why I need to introduce a temporary simple type as we can think of the `[foo]` as like a function parameter, but the use case of looking up a structure member would seem to be a frequent requirement, so what is the rationale for not supporting the usage? Or is there another way to avoid the temporary variable?

Comment: And why not just `std::list<S>::iterator it = std::find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), [s1] (S s)  { return s.S1 == s1.S1; } );`?
BTW, why don't you use capture by reference if your lambda does not live past the scope end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11 I think you're stuck with adding in the intermediate variable. In C++14 you can use a capture with an initializer:

```
std::list<S>::iterator it = std::find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), 
    [foo = s1.S1] (S s) { return s.S1 == foo; } );
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```