# C++ function that returns an iterator to first record with the given value

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, listiterator, const-iterator

I am trying to create a simple function returns an iterator to first record with the given value.

Comment: -1. Have you spend at least 1 second with searching about this on the internet? There are countless examples, like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394000/c-find-if-lambda

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
std::list<records>::const_iterator findrecords(const std::list<records>& registry, 
                                               const std::string& student_id) 
{
    return std::find_if(registry.begin(),
                        registry.end(), 
                        [&]( const records &r ) { return r.student_id == student_id; } );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct records
{
    std::string student_id;
};    

std::list<records>::const_iterator findrecords(const std::list<records>& registry,
    const std::string& student_id)
{
    return std::find_if(registry.begin(),
        registry.end(),
        [&](const records &r) { return r.student_id == student_id; });
}

int main()
{
    std::list<records> registry = { { "A" }, { "B" }, { "C" } };

    std::string student_id( "B" );

    auto it = findrecords(registry, student_id);

    if (it != registry.end())
    {
        std::cout << it->student_id << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
B
```

Comment: Error C2064 term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments Records c:\visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\list 1556

Comment: @JasonW Try the demonstrative program. Take into account that I defined the class records by myself. It can differ from your class.